# Looking for a portfolio CMS or virtual business card CMS

Tags: php, web-applications

Is there a portfolio cms? To build an about me page with my resume and portfolio?

**Edited:**

I want a content management system just for portfolio.

Comment: Nothing! I don't want something like wordpress, joomla, ... I'm trying idslot now, it seems good

Comment: Please note if you ask on StackOverflow, you should tell us about what you have tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: @xiaomao He tried, it didn't work! (I'm such a troll...)

Comment: Thanks Burhan, I know about about.me. I found my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IDSlot is a portfolio CMS](http://idslot.org/). (It's free and open source)

> IDSlot is a set of methods for generating a distinguished Web presence
>   of a person on the internet. That presence consist of some kind of
>   content that refers to the person/identity, including about,
>   portfolio, (social) links, contact information and resume as default
>   plugins. It's customizable and theme-able.